# How to choose the base class method when argument is a std::function type

Tags: c++, c++14, handler, std-function

I'm implementing a program where a class b inherits from class a. Both classes have a handler which can be set using a method called set_handler. In main I have an object of b but want to call the set_handler method inherited from a. Apparently the ADL (argument dependent lookup) doesn't work as I expect.

Consider the code below. It has a compiler error. Is it possible to force the compiler to pick a::set_handler()? Or is there a better way to implement a similar functionality if you aren't allowed to change class a and the method for setting the handler in class b isn't changed to something different from set_handler?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class x
{
public:
    std::string print() const
    {
        return "Throw from x";
    }
};

class y
{
public:
    std::string print() const
    {
        return "Throw from y";
    }
};

typedef std::function<void(const x &)> x_handler;
typedef std::function<void(const y &)> y_handler;

class a
{
protected:
    x_handler handler_;

public:
    x_handler set_handler(x_handler handler)
    {
        handler_.swap(handler);
        return handler;
    }

    void trigger_x()
    {
        handler_(x());
    }

};

class b : public a
{
private:
    y_handler handler_;

public:
    y_handler set_handler(y_handler handler)
    {
        handler_.swap(handler);
        return handler;
    }
    void trigger_y()
    {
        handler_(y());
    }
    void trigger_x()
    {
        a::handler_(x());
    }
};

void x_handler_impl(const x &e)
{
    std::cout << e.print() << std::endl;
}

void y_handler_impl(const y &e)
{
    std::cout << e.print() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    a obj_a;
    b obj_b;
    obj_a.set_handler(&x_handler_impl);
    obj_b.set_handler(&x_handler_impl); // Compiler complains: error: cannot convert 'void (*)(const x&)' to 'y_handler' {aka 'std::function<void(const y&)>'}
    obj_a.trigger_x();
    obj_b.trigger_x();
}
```

I'm compiling using the following command:

```
g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -std=c++14 main.cpp -o main.exe
```

I tried using static_cast<x_handler>(&x_handler_impl) to force the cast to the correct type but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: whats the ADL in here?

Comment: I might have a wrong understanding of ADL but I expect that the compiler can use ADL to differentiate between set_handler(y_handler) and set_handler(x_handler).

Comment: Overload resolution is actually rather simple here: You call `set_handler` on an object of type `b`, compiler finds `b::set_handler` with non-matching signature hence the error. I dont think this has anythign to do with ADL (fwiw: https://godbolt.org/z/c3E7adcvq)

Comment: BTW, this is just overload resolution (ADL is for unqualified function calls, like `swap(a, b)`, where name lookup can find different functions dependent on the type of the arguments). As the linked answer states, `b::set_handler` hides `a::set_handler` entirely, and you need `using a::set_handler` to bring it back.